# Restarting cron after changing crontab file?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, cron-task

Do I have to restart cron after changing the crontable file?

Comment: Not to disregard @leonbloy's answer, but I found that implementing my linux's first cron job (a correctly formatted per minute job) didn't action until the system was rebooted. `sudo service cron restart` wasn't tested.

Comment: @geotheory yikes I sure hope I don't have to restart my prod server any time I update my crontab (and I don't).

Answer (score 822, accepted):

No.

From the [cron man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/cron/):

> ...cron will then examine the modification time on all crontabs 
>     and reload those which have changed.  Thus cron need not be restarted 
>     whenever a crontab file is modified

But if you just want to make sure its done anyway,

```
sudo service cron reload
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/cron reload
```

Comment: If using cron.d folder, symlinked crontabs will not be reloaded. How can I force a reload?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `/etc/init.d/cron restart` ?

Comment: Ah it's that easy. It's now `sudo service cron restart`.

Comment: Better option is reload - it can be initiated by non-root user:
```/etc/init.d/cron reload```

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Possibly `crond` instead of `cron`.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that it's not always true.  See geotheory's comment underneath the question.  I, too, was bit by this.  I made a change to the crontab file via `sudo crontab -e`, saved the change by `Ctrl + X`, and went away assuming `cron` would pick it up (due to this answer being so highly upvoted). Then, days later my client reports that the cron is still running on the old cycle.  So - honestly - if you want to be safe - just restart either `cron` or the system, and don't play around with wasted time testing, which you'll have to do despite this highly-upvoted answer.

Comment: sudo service crond reload works for me to reload de cron definition files on /etc/crontab

Comment: On FreeBSD and OpenBSD you need to restart the cron service after create a file under /var/cron/tabs/user or /var/cron/tabs/user

Comment: On my Raspberry Pi 3+ with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS the only command that worked for me was: `sudo service cron reload`. It was also the only command which gave a response: `* Reloading configuration files for periodic command scheduler cron`.

Comment: I guess this is distribution-specific. On Ubuntu 20.04, with default (Vixie) cron, plain edits (with `vim`, not `crontab`) to a user-specific crontab (`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/user-foo`) *are* picked up and acted on immediately; tested with a per-minute echo and `tail`ing the user's mail file. This is also true if you simply copy in the user's cron file during installation.

Answer (score 80):

On CentOS with cPanel `sudo /etc/init.d/crond reload` does the trick.

On CentOS7: `sudo systemctl start crond.service`

Comment: Thanks for the CentOs 7 line

Comment: // , To reload `crond`, rather than just start it on the increasingly horrible systemd, run `sudo systemctl reload crond.service`.

Comment: @NathanBasanese Reloading `cron` on SystemD now is considered black magic: `sudo systemctl reload crond` fails with `Failed to reload cron.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit cron.service.` (Ubuntu 18.04).  Read: Heads off, we all are pwned by the syndrome: "SystemD, there can be only one".  If reload is not done automagically behind the scenes, you are bust!  Do not even think about fixing it, like you did for the last 3 (or more) decades!  Read: **The world of Windows has finally swallowed Debian:  If there's something strange under the hood, what you gonna do?  Restart!**

Comment: Restart is more than just reload. Isn't there a clean reload option available for Centos?

Comment: @Tino you can install cronie

Answer (score 47):

I had a similar issue on 16.04 VPS Digital Ocean. If you are changing crontabs, make sure to run

```
sudo service cron restart
```

Comment: I see only `reload` is enough. No need `restart`. Thanks. :)

Comment: In my case Rasperian with PI zero and changes in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root I had to use `restart`

Comment: Had the same problem as @mikep on an old openSUSE 10 machine. Only `restart` worked.

Answer (score 21):

## Commands for RHEL/Fedora/CentOS/Scientific Linux user

1. Start cron service

   - To start the cron service, use: `/etc/init.d/crond start`
   - OR RHEL/CentOS 5.x/6.x user: `service crond start`
   - OR RHEL/Centos Linux 7.x user: `systemctl start crond.service`
2. Stop cron service

   - To stop the cron service, use: `/etc/init.d/crond stop`
   - OR RHEL/CentOS 5.x/6.x user: `service crond stop`
   - OR RHEL/Centos Linux 7.x user: `systemctl stop crond.service`
3. Restart cron service

   - To restart the cron service, use: `/etc/init.d/crond restart`
   - OR RHEL/CentOS 5.x/6.x user: `service crond restart`
   - OR RHEL/Centos Linux 7.x user: `systemctl restart crond.service`

## Commands for Ubuntu/Mint/Debian based Linux distro

1. Debian Start cron service

   - To start the cron service, use: `/etc/init.d/cron start`
   - OR `sudo /etc/init.d/cron start`
   - OR `sudo service cron start`
2. Debian Stop cron service

   - To stop the cron service, use: `/etc/init.d/cron stop`
   - OR `sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop`
   - OR `sudo service cron stop`
3. Debian Restart cron service

   - To restart the cron service, use: `/etc/init.d/cron restart`
   - OR `sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`
   - OR `sudo service cron restart`

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-start-restart-cron/

Comment: This does not appear to attempt to answer the question at the top of this page at all. Please review the [help] and in particular [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 17):

Depending on distribution, using "cron reload" might do nothing. To paste a snippet out of init.d/cron (debian squeeze):

```
reload|force-reload) log_daemon_msg "Reloading configuration files for periodic command scheduler" "cron"
    # cron reloads automatically
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;
```

Some developer/maintainer relied on it reloading, but doesn't, and in this case there's not a way to force reload. I'm generating my crontab files as part of a deploy, and unless somehow the length of the file changes, the changes are not reloaded.

Comment: perhaps HUPping the process works in systems with service reload disabled?

Answer (score 14):

1. If file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` edited via SFTP client  - `service cron restart` needed.
   Reload service not work.
2. If edited file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` via console linux (nano, mc) - restart NOT needed.
3. If edited cron via `crontab -e` - restart NOT needed.

Answer (score 12):

try this one for centos 7 : service crond reload

Comment: Or `systemctl reload crond`

Answer (score 7):

Try this out: `sudo cron reload`
It works for me on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Doesn't work on my Raspberry Pi 3+ with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 5):

Try this: `service crond restart`, Hence it's `crond` not `cron`.

Comment: `crond` unrecognized service. It work with `cron` for me. my OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4):

There are instances wherein cron needs to be restarted in order for the start up script to work. There's nothing wrong in restarting the cron.

sudo service cron restart

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS (my version is 6.5) when editing crontab you must close the editor to reflect your changes in CRON.

```
crontab -e
```

After that command You can see that new entry appears in /var/log/cron

```
Sep 24 10:44:26 ***** crontab[17216]: (*****) BEGIN EDIT (*****)
```

But only saving crontab editor after making some changes does not work. You must leave the editor to reflect changes in cron. After exiting new entry appears in the log:

```
Sep 24 10:47:58 ***** crontab[17216]: (*****) END EDIT (*****)
```

From this point changes you made are visible to CRON.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04
* Usage: /etc/init.d/cron {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload}